# Serializing extension properties to JSON

Tags: json, serialization, kotlin

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    val prop1 = "value1"
    val prop2 = "value2"
}
```

and an extension property in another file:

```
val MyClass.prop3
    get() = "something else"
```

Serializing a `MyClass` instance as JSON I'm getting:

```
{ prop1 : "value1", prop2 : "value2" }
```

I know that Kotlin extension functions and properties are compiled to JVM as static methods, so I'm wondering if there is a way (or an utility) to serialize extension properties of a class as well al regular properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell in advance what extensions will be available at the runtime for any particular class. I can write my own an extension field for your `MyClass` and your code will never know that. Moreover, extensions can be available or not in a particular places of a module depending on the imports (remember that you need to import an extension method or field?).

So, there is no efficient way for a serializer to know about your extensions and thus serialize them.